# Python: Make an image composite, resize it and then make a final composite with the new resized image

Tags: python, image, resize, composite

I'm new to python and I'm experimenting with images. So far I've managed to use the composite function without a problem but I'm having troubles when I try to make a composite image, then resize it and then make a final composite with a last layer (with same dimensions as the resized image).

The code I've got so far:

from PIL import Image, ImageOps

for item in traits:

```
im1 = Image.open(f'./preimages/backgrounds/{backgroundfiles[item["background"]]}.png').convert('RGBA')
im2 = Image.open(f'./preimages/secbackgrounds/{secbackgroundfiles[item["secbackground"]]}.png').convert('RGBA') 
im3 = Image.open(f'./preimages/image/{imagefiles[item["image"]]}.png').convert('RGBA') 


#Create each composite
com1 = Image.alpha_composite(im1, im2) 
com2 = Image.alpha_composite(com1, im3)
```

## Convert to RGB and resize

```
rgb_im = com2.convert('RGB') 
imB = (rgb_im.resize((1400,1400), Image.NEAREST).save("imb.png")
```

#Create final composite

```
im4 = Image.open(f'./preimages/lastlayer/{lastlaayerfiles[item["lastlayer"]]}.png').convert('RGBA') ## added
com3 = Image.alpha_composite(imB, im4)  


 
file_name = str(item["Id"]) + ".png"
rgb_im.save("./Testoutput/" + file_name)
print(f'{str(item["Id"])} done')
```

Thank you very much for your help, I love this community.

Comment: Where is `com6` created?

Comment: What's the point of `./preimages/XXX`? That's just `preimages/XXX`. Likewise `./Testoutput/XXX` is just the same as `Testoutput/XXX`.

Comment: hey thanks, it was com2, not com6.. and ok to know ./ is the same as just the folder name :)

Answer (score 0):

so I found a solution:

from PIL import ImageChops

After creating the first composite round

## Convert to RGB

```
newsize = (1400,1400)
imB = (com2.resize(newsize, Image.NEAREST)) ## to genarate 1400x1400 
finalComp = ImageChops.multiply(imB, im4)


 
file_name = str(item["tokenId"]) + ".png"
finalComp.save("./Testoutput/" + file_name)
print(f'{str(item["Id"])} done')
```